# stable/prometheus-operator persistent grafana organization name

Tags: grafana, azure-aks, prometheus-operator

We have a `stable/prometheus-operator` *(chart: prometheus-operator-8.9.1 , app version: 036.0)* running in our AKS cluster, which comes with `Grafana`v6.5.2 installed *(later I upgraded it to v6.6.2 by manually changing the image tag of the grafana deployment)*.

What I would like to know is that if it is possible to persist the **Organization name** of Grafana so that it survives restarts (cluster, pod etc).
[image: configuration\preferences]

I've tried to find a reference how to do this in [Grafana's documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/configuration/#configure-with-environment-variables) especially via environment variables (or configmaps) but all I could find was a setting for anonymous users:

```
[auth.anonymous]
enabled = true
org_role = Viewer
org_name = Company Server Stats
```

Comment: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/2908 ?

Comment: Yes, definitely seems like my issue. I added comment there and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now this doesnt seem supported, there's an issue open on this: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/2908

Comment: For the time being there is no out-of-the-box way to do this. The suggestion of using Post hook doesn't work because it is a pod lifecycle event not container, so the API won't be up to receive the command. So I accept this as the answer.